# Show that this function is convex

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}c_i\exp(\alpha_i^{T}x)$$
where $c_i >0.$

Show that $\log(f)$ is convex.

I got a hint to write the numerator of second derivative as sum of exponentials with coefficients and then use inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean to show coefficients are postitive.

I was trying to write at leat the second partial with respect to $x_1$, here is what I got:

I will write $f'$ to mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$ etc.

$$(\log(f(x)))'' = \frac{f''f - f'f'}{f^2}$$
Where
$$f' =\sum_{i = 1}^{m}c_i{\alpha_{i}}_1\exp(\alpha_i^{T}x)$$
$$f'' = \sum_{i = 1}^{m}c_i{\alpha_{i}^2}_1\exp(\alpha_i^{T}x)$$

I tried to get anything out of this but I got nothing.
If you have a better approach I would gladly hear it.